# Angular2 router3alpha - How to get activeRoute

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How do we style an element with css-class "active" with the new angular2.rc3 & router3.0.0alpha6?

The old approaches do not seem to work any more and there is little documentation yet on the finer details of the new router...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide those "old approaches", it is always useful to point what you have tried before others will try to help you. Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks sanket to pointing me to the other thread!

It seems in v3 the router does have an easily accessible way to get the current route:

```
this.router.url
```

So a possible solution to style the active route component with a css class is:

```
<li [class.active]="isActiveRoute('/myroute')">
    <a [routerLink]="['/myroute']">
</li>
```

and in your navigation / menu component:

```
isActiveRoute(route: string) : boolean
{
    if(this.router.url === route)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems there was an update and the best way to do this now is `<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set something on the actual `routerLink` anchor there's some functionality now in V3 to make it a little easier:

`<li>
<a [routerLink]="['/']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Home</a>
</li>`

Where whatever you put equal to `routerLinkActive` will become the class of the anchor if that route is currently active. Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for though.

I found this information out via searching the `Angular2` issues on their Github Repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9426. Sounds like there's talk of having some default behavior where a class `router-link-active` is set to the currently active route anchor (as it was in previous versions of the router).

EDIT: If for some reason you want to add a class to an element outside of the html with `routerLink, etc.` here's a way I've cobbled together:

```
export class App implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


@HostBinding('class.home') isHome = false;
  constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.router = router;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.isHome = e.url === '/';
      }
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931429/6417489